# Can a git repository use different transport protocols per branch?

Tags: git, github, ssh, https, network-protocols

Server blocks outgoing SSH on port 22.

Trying to connect a new repo to an existing private GitHub repo.

On server:

```
git init .
git remote add git@github.com:<github_username>/repo_name.git
```

Strangest result sees my unable to communicate with GitHub whilst checked out into the `main` branch because it uses SSH transport.

However, on the only secondary branch, communication with GitHub works fine, seemingly because it's connecting to a different domain: `ssh.github.com` and / or using HTTPS, however I do not recall ever connecting to the repository over HTTPS! Let alone for one branch and not the other.

`git config --list` only shows one URL:

```
push.default=simple
core.autocrlf=false
grep.linenumber=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.sshcommand=ssh -vvv
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:<github_username>/repo_name.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.main.remote=origin
branch.main.merge=refs/heads/main
branch.2nd.remote=origin
branch.2nd.merge=refs/heads/2nd
```

Debugging whilst checked out into **'2nd'** branch:

```
debug2: resolving "ssh.github.com" port 443
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [20.248.137.50] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
```

Debugging whilst checked out into **'main'** branch:

```
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [20.248.137.48] port 22.
# Hangs here (firewall) but why the different address / protocol?
```

Has anyone experienced one branch attempting to use SSH transport whilst another uses HTTPS?

I wasn't aware this was possible but it seemingly is.

Update for @LeGEC:

Within the ***'2nd'*** branch:

```
ssh -vv git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10+esm2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 22: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "ssh.github.com" port 443
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ssh.github.com [20.248.137.50] port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
```

So, again, `ssh.github.com` and `443`

Within the ***'main'*** branch:

```
ssh -vv git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10+esm2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 22: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [20.248.137.48] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

And again, `github.com` and `22`

Comment: Branches aren't Remotes.

Comment: don't you have something like a versioned `.env` file that your shell or some part of your system takes into account ? can you check `env` in both cases ? if you run `ssh --vv git@github.com`, do you see the same difference in how the name is resolved ?

Comment: it's definitely not git alone, there is something else that changes your context.

Comment: hmmm ... I just recalled you can have an [`[includeIf "onbranch:foo"]` section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-codeonbranchcode) in your configuration. Can you check whether this is the case ? most probably in your repo's `.git/config`, or perhaps in your global `~/.gitconfig` file ?

Comment: @LeGEC no `includeIf` in either `.gitconfig` or `/.git/config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a visible difference in your two `ssh -vv` outputs :

in the first one ("Within the '2nd' branch:"), you can see:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: /root/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
```

which doesn't show up in the other trace.

---

If your repo versions the ssh config files for the account you are running on, then this can obviously change the way `ssh` behaves if you change branches ...

Since that account appears to be `root`, I will also give you a very strong warning against using git in such a setup.

`git` has good features for a versioning tool, it however has a few foot shooters and is definitely not a provisioning tool. You probably don't want `root` to run hooks, to trigger merge conflicts in some central configuration files, or run `git clean -f` or `git restore` on your disk.

Comment: Out of interest, what tool(s) would you suggest for provisioning?

Comment: Thanks for being a decent person about this. I thought the `/root/.ssh/config` file was missing but it's not. Explains a lot but perhaps not why that file kicks in for the '2nd' branch but not the `main` branch. Nevermind. had enough of the trolling in this question so I'll probably delete it rather than give that unkind cyber bullying a platform. Wanted to make sure your help was acknowledged though, even if deleting may remove credit. Sorry.

Comment: no worries about the deletion :)

Comment: about your `.ssh/config` : my guess is that it is versioned in at least one of your branches (you can confirm that by running `git ls-tree -r <HEAD or branch name or commit sha>`), so when you checkout to/from `2nd` branch, its content gets modified (if you have no `.ssh/config` file in your `main` branch, it gets completely deleted when you run `git checkout main`)

Comment: my remark about not using git as a provisioning tool is a generic catch-all remark. I really don't recommend doing that on your main system. If you run it on a system which you can easily recreate (for example: a VM, or within a container ...), perhaps you can fly with it. I have no provisioning framework in mind, in my own case my deployment needs were simple enough, I could answer them by writing shell scripts. In those situations, the first things I had to script was: set the correct access rights on files (owner, group, acl), handle services when some specific files were changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try and compare `git config -l --show-origin --show-scope` in both environments.
That should show something related to `ssh.github.com`.

Try also the same command after [`export GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=1`](https://git-scm.com/docs/api-trace2#_the_event_format_target): you can compare both event sets:

```bash
export GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=~/log.event.main
git fetch origin main

export GIT_TRACE2_EVENT=~/log.event.2nd
git switch 2nd
git fetch origin 2nd

git diff --no-index --color-words=. ~/log.event.main ~/log.event.2nd
```

Comment: `git config -l --show-origin --show-scope` just dumps the usage summary for `git config -l`. Maybe those long options are not available in git `2.7.4` ?

Comment: Alas, the log files are not being created.

Comment: @pd_au 2.7.4? I wouldn't know, I was not born yet. Any chance you could upgrade Git?

Comment: Upgraded to `2.40.0` but tests you kindly suggested proved inconclusive, partially because there's some perhaps weirdness (corruption?) going on:

`git fetch origin main
error: cannot run : No such file or directory
error: cannot run : No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork`
... and @LeGEC identified the `config` file making a difference (though it's somewhat still a mystery why it only kicks in for one branch, which was the primary / entire crux of this question). Nonetheless. too much trolling from one other user so I've had it with this. Thanks for your help and thoughts.

Comment: @pd_au Great, I am glad you have found the solution. And I have upvoted LeGEC's answer.